# Is sequence $a_n=\frac{1\ \cdot\ 3\ \cdot\ \cdots\ \cdot (2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdots\ \cdot 2n}$ bounded below, can I compute the serie $\sum_{n\geq1}a_n$?

Tags: calculus

Given the sequence $a_n=\frac{1\ \cdot\ 3\ \cdot\ 5\cdot \ \cdots\  \cdot (2n-1)}{1\ \cdot\ 3\ \cdot\ 5\cdot \ \cdots\ \cdot 2n}$. Show that  the sequence is decreasing and bounded below.

If we have the sequence $$a_n=\frac{1\ \cdot\ 3\ \cdot\ 5\cdot \ \cdots\  \cdot (2n-1)}{2\ \cdot\ 4\ \cdot\ 6\cdot \ \cdots\ \cdot 2n},$$

now we have $2n-1<2n$ for all $n>1$ then 
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1\ \cdot\ 3\ \cdot\ 5\cdot \ \cdots\  \cdot (2n+1)}{2\ \cdot\ 4\ \cdot\ 6\cdot \ \cdots\ \cdot 2n+2}<\frac{1\ \cdot\ 3\ \cdot\ 5\cdot \ \cdots\  \cdot (2n-1)}{2\ \cdot\ 4\ \cdot\ 6\cdot \ \cdots\ \cdot 2n}=a_n$$
then $a_n>a_{n+1}$

How can I compute the serie $\sum_{n\geq1}a_n$?

Comment: You have two different definitions of $a_n$ in your question. Is the one with denominator $2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot \cdots (2n)$ correct?

Comment: Do you mean the series $\sum _{n \geq 1} a_n $ or the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$?

Comment: It is bounded below by $0$

Comment: Yes, $\sum_{n\geq1}a_n$

Comment: Are you supposed to know the gamma function ? If you do, even if the series diverges, the  partial sums can be (quite well) approximated.

Comment: The series is divergent by the p-test and the partial sums have a nice closed form.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_{n}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = \frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n} \tag{0}$$
then it is not difficult to check that the sequence given by
$$ b_n = \frac{\sqrt{\pi(n+1/4)}}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n} \tag{1}$$
is increasing since $\frac{b_{n+1}^2}{b_n^2}>1$ is equivalent to a simple polynomial inequality, and converging to one by Stirling's inequality. It follows that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n \color{red}{=}-1+\frac{N+1}{2^{2N+1}}\binom{2N+2}{N+1} \color{blue}{\approx} \sqrt{\frac{4N+1}{\pi}} \tag{2}$$
where $\color{red}{=}$ holds as a consequence of creative telescoping, or the fact that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}},\qquad \sum_{n=0}^{N}a_n = [x^N]\frac{1}{(1-x)\sqrt{1-x}}=2[x^N]\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} \tag{3}$$
and $\color{blue}{\approx}$ follows from $b_n\approx 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: compare your series to the harmonic series:

$a_1=1/2$

$a_2=3/8>1/3$

By induction, if $a_n\geq\frac{1}{n+1}$ then:

$a_{n+1}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}a_n\geq\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\frac{1}{n+1}\geq\frac{1}{n+2}$

So your series diverges by comparison to $1/2+1/3+...$

Comment: Yes, it diverges but the partial sums can be (quite well) approximated.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I'm kind of lazy to think about it... could you expand?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Never Mind. I see now that the partial sums have a closed form.

Comment: I asked the OP if he/she is supposed to know about the gamma function. Using it, we can express $\sum_{n=1}^p a_n$ in a closed form and, if needed, admiiting large value of $p$, make a Taylor expansion of the result.